# get MAX or MIN (signed) in Verilog?

Tags: max, verilog, fpga

I'm trying to make a function to get the max value (I'm working with signed numbers).

This is my function:

```
  function integer max(input integer  a, input integer  b, input integer  c, input integer  d);
    integer i;
    begin

            max = a;
    if ($signed(b) > $signed(max))
        max = b;
    if ($signed(c) > $signed(max))
        max = c;
    if ($signed(d) > $signed(max))
        max = d;

    end

  endfunction
```

For some reason, this is not calcuting the max value of signed numbers. This is taking the numbers as unsigned.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Why do you use the $signed()? Integers are be default signed.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I put $signed() or not. The function is not calculating the result with signed numbers. Why?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you called the function with arguments and the results it gives?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code in a simulator and have found the `max` function working as expected.

I can think of three reasons:

1. You have an error somewhere else.
2. Your expectations are wrong.
3. Your simulator is broken (which I doubt.)

Comment: this is the entire module and the function is not taking in consideration the $signed, If removed it, the result is the same: https://pastebin.com/qMn9gkFG

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are assuming the argument to your `max` function are unsigned, which is why you attempted using the `$signed` function. But they will have already be converted to signed integers as part of calling the function. You are trying to pass in 8-bit unsigned values, which get 0-extended to 32-bit signed values. You need to do one of the following:

- Change the input argument type to match the actual types you are
  passing. Then the cast `$signed` inside the function makes sense.
- Change the actual argument types to match the function
  argument types. Do the cast to signed outside the function call, or make the variables signed to begin with.